# What an input space exactly is in the context of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-mining

I've been confused about various "space"s in machine learning for a long time.

I've checked out [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/427446/257182), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/322934/258139) and this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/419095/244425).

I am trying to get understanding through some concrete examples like this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/419095/244425).

Consider the example in this [video](https://youtu.be/eqEc66RFY0I?t=232)

[image]

Assume each channel of each pixel has 256 possible integer values and we are using rgb color scheme, which means, there are $256^3$ possible values in each pixel.

Assume each image consists $64*64$ pixels, is the input space = feature space = a set of $64^2*256^3$ possible arrays that each has a dimension of $64 \times 64 \times 64$?

Comment: In your example, the input space is $X^{64^2}$ where $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, 256\}^3$. So that's $64^2 \times 256^3$ features.

Comment: This is a vague concept, not formally defined well. Closest analogy would be the vector space span by the vectors $X$. Obviously, feature space is a design choice and could be much larger than the input space i.e., think about CNNs. Then again it depends on the convention/definition practitioner chooses.

Comment: @fuDL Are you asking how many different $64 \times 64$ images can be represented in RGB and greyscale representations where each pixel can take on one of 256 values? Or are you asking for a definition of a particular concept? Or are you asking something else?

Answer (score -1):

Single line answer to your question i.e. *is the input space = feature space*?

**Answer:** No, input_shape is not equal to feature_space.

#### Discussion

Consider you have 10 images, each is 64x64 pixels and 3 channels i.e. RGB.
[image]
For this example, the input shape for each image is image Height x width x No_channel i.e. 64x64x3 for color image and 64 x 64 x 1 for grey scale image i.e. (64,64,3) for color and (64, 64, 1) for grey scale image. In other word, each input has 3 planes (R,G,B) with 2D array 64 x 64 ( image pixel size).

[image]